# How to setup In memory cache for RestSharp Client in .NET Core Console Application

Tags: c#, caching, console-application, restsharp, .net-6.0

I have C# console application in .NET 6.

I am researching the setup of a RestSharp client first i need to setup in memory caching.
I have done an implementation in asp.net that uses `System.Runtime.Caching`

Example of the difference :

```
  public class InMemoryCache : ICacheService
  {
    public T Get<T>(string cacheKey) where T : class
    {
        return MemoryCache.Default.Get(cacheKey) as T;
    }
```

the **MemoryCache.Default** is not part of the Extension Library `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`
like the
However with the console application with .NET 6 I have to use  `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`

How would i implement the above with using `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory`

Also here is my configuration

```
 //class Program
 private static InMemoryCache _cache;

 //Main

 services.AddMemoryCache();
 var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
 _cache = serviceProvider.GetService<InMemoryCache>();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your own wrapper around `IMemoryCache` - you should inject `IMemoryCache` into `InMemoryCache` and use it (`InMemoryCache` should also be registered in the DI as `InMemoryCache` so you can resolve it):

```
public class InMemoryCache : ICacheService
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public InMemoryCache(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        _cache = cache;
    }
    public T Get<T>(string cacheKey) where T : class
    {
        return _cache.Get<T>(cacheKey);
    }
}
```